# VMware workstation player cannot use the suspend button when the software upgrade to version 15

Tags: vmware-player

VMware workstation player cannot use the suspend button when the software upgrade to version 15

Error message

> Error while suspending: The virtual machine cannot be suspended until
>   VMware Tools finishes running the script.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the Power controls are not available in VMware Workstation Player. To chage this setting you will need to manually edit the .vmx file for the VM as follows:

1. Ensure that the VM is shutdown and VMware Workstation Player is not running.
2. Open the .vmx file for the VM in your preferred text editor. (Notepad.exe will work.)
3. If there is already an entry in the .vmx file of powerType.Suspend = "soft" change it to powerType.Suspend = "hard".
4. If the entry does not exist add it.
5. Save the changes to the .vmx file and close it.
6. Run the VM and see if Suspend now works.

[Reference](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/589891)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try to expand the play and pause icon and select the suspend option.
(Tente expandir o ícone de play e pause e selecione a opção suspender.)

[image]